# Establish the extent of an axis in d3 post-render

Tags: d3.js

I want to be able to, given an existing d3 chart, determine the y-axis extent.

I've tried:

```
d3.select(chartToUpdate).select('svg').select('g.axis').extent
```

and

```
d3.select(chartToUpdate).select('svg').select('x.axis').extent
```

and numerous variants on the above but with no success. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to take the domain from the scale...If you can't find then post the whole code i ll locate for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Axis within D3 you usually base it upon a [Scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales). For example a linear scale may be:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 100000]) // Input Range
                    .range([0, 100]);    // Output Range (e.g. 100 svg units wide)

var axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale);
```

So this means at any point you should be able to call `scale.domain()` to get the range of inputs for the visualization. Note that typically you'd drive this dynamically, so you'd probably have:

```
scale.domain([0, d3.max(myNumberArray)]);
```